# Eclipse shortcut uncategorized and uneditable

Tags: eclipse

**Ecipse 4.3.2**

In previous version I had a shortcut to export Android Application with `STRG+ALT+SHIFT+A`.
But since some update if I press this combination I'll have to decide between `Export Android Application` or `Add Artifact to Target Platform`. That's annoying!

In settings menu there is no entry. (Only at *'conflicts'*
I researched where the short key file storage is and there is also no entry for that.
I exported all shortcuts to csv and there stands that is **uncategorized**.

I haven't able to edit it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Filter

  - uncheck all
- search it
- >now you can edit it
- "apply"